# Is there a way to fix resource badcfg get error in console

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Am getting this error in my console

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array&p2=GET&p3=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.2tag2.com%2F%2Frequests%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3DgetChat%26id%3D1
```

Help me resolve this. This is my code **service.js**

```
.factory('A', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        ;
        return { 
       Chat: $resource(site_url + '/requests/api.php?action=:action&uid1=:uid1&uid2=:uid2', {
                action: '@action',
                uid1: '@uid1',
                uid2: '@uid2'
        }),

        };
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

“To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.”

In your case, since the api returns an array, change `action=get` to `action=query`.

As stated in the debug:
“By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.”

Try the following:

```
var Chat = $resource(
  site_url + 
  '/requests/api.php?action=:action&uid1=:uid1&uid2=:uid2', 
  {
    action: '@action',
    uid1: '@uid1',
    uid2: '@uid2'
  });

var chats = Chat.query({ action: 'getChat', uid1: 1});

chats.$promise.then(function() {
 console.log(chats);
 return chats;
});
```

Consider building your [API Restfull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). In your example above this will mean some altering of your code and api architecture.

To retrieve your chats it is better to build your API calls like below:

Retrieving all chats:
`site_url + '/v1/chats'`

Retrieving a chat by id
`site_url + '/v1/chats/:chatId'`

Comment: Am failing to run it I have updated my initial code

Comment: Please create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs) example of your code so I can help you in a better way.